# Session clearing issue

Tags: java, session, spring-mvc

I am facing with the issues is Iam showing a error message in the page(newpwd.jsp) via

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("currpwderror", "Enter Correct Password");
```

it is showing first time with out any problem. But at the second time loading this(newpwd.jsp) page this message shown there. the message should not be shown there on loading. 
I know this problem is because of not clearing the session. But I don't know the solution 
Please help me. 
In jsp:

```
<span style="color:#FF0000; align:right" id="lblmsg_log">${currpwderror }</span>
```

java

```
 request.getSession().setAttribute("currpwderror", "Enter Correct Password");

ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("redirect:"+projectUrl+"newpwd.html");             
            return modelAndView;
```

Comment: Why are you setting the error message in session? You should ideally do it in request.

Comment: I used request.setAttribute("currpwderror", "Enter Correct Password");  but not show the message

Comment: @Manish  i used request method but doesn't show  and I am using simple form that s why can't use return showform(responce,request,errors)

Comment: You should show us the relevant parts of your servlet, especially the code forwarding to the JSP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be setting the error in your request/response cycle. I mena the response you are sending back ideally. Session is not the place for that.

Comment: I used request.setAttribute("currpwderror", "Enter Correct Password"); but not show the message

Answer (score 1):

the issue is resolved. By

```
request.setAttribute("currpwderror", "Enter Correct Password");

            ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("newpwd");             
            return modelAndView;
```

Thanks for the response. I learned new thing.

Answer (score 0):

In your java class, remove the `currpwderror` attribute from session when user enters the password.

Comment: currpwderror is reference key for showing in jsp. In jsp <span style="color:#FF0000; align:right" id="lblmsg_log">${currpwderror }</span>

Comment: you can put complete `span` block in an `if` condition in JSP

Answer (score 0):

Why are you redirecting? Cannot you simply forward your request and use the model to carry the error message instead? Also, why not using Spring's Validation facility?

Comment: Ia m using simle form that s why not using Spring's Validation facility